# Can electrons, upon interaction, change each other's phase?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wavefunction, orbitals

Imagine two hydrogen atoms which are close together, but not yet bonded. According to molecular orbital theory, the wavefunctions of their 1s electrons have to be in phase for them to interfere constructively and create a bonding orbital that is lower in energy. Does that mean than even if their phases are opposite to start with, one of them will cause the other to change phase?

Answer (score 0):

To describe two electrons in a hydrogen molecule (or a helium atom) one really needs to solve the Schrödinger equation for the two-electron wave function. The question of interference of two wave functions come in the context of trying to get such a solution approximately from single electron orbitals.

When we do try to construct the solution from single electron orbitals, we need to consider the possibilities that they have the same or different phases. These possibilities lead to two different energies, of which one is lower than the energy of the unbound atoms and the other is higher than this energy. Thus, in the case of the constructive interference the bound state is realized, whereas in the case of destructive interference the two atoms don't bind. I stress however that a) we are dealing with approximation, and b) we are discussing a mathematical solution rather than a physical experiment where two atoms are created with particular phases and expected to bind or not.